# Unable to deserialize a Object ArrayList

Tags: java, object, serialization, arraylist, deserialization

I have an ArrayList of Objects (UploadedItem) called UploadList which I am able serialize automatically after every update. I am unable however to deserialize on startup. Here is the classes which are apart of the process.

UploadModel:

```
public class UploadModel extends Observable {

    ArrayList<UploadItem> UploadedList = new ArrayList<>();
    Deserialize _deserialize = new Deserialize();
    Serialize _serialize = new Serialize();
    private UploadItem name;

    public UploadModel ()
    {
        _deserialize.startup();
    }

    public void addUpload(String[] ToUpload)         
    {
       UploadItem _UploadItem = new UploadItem();
       _UploadItem.ArrayToString(ToUpload);
       UploadedList.add(_UploadItem);

       setChanged();

       notifyObservers(UploadedList);

       _serialize.save(UploadedList);
    }
}
```

UploadItem (This whats in my arraylist):

```
public class UploadItem implements Serializable{

    String VideoTitle;
    String VideoPath;
    String ThumbnailPath;
    String VideoDesc;
    String VideoTags;

    public void ArrayToString(String[] ToUpload){
    VideoTitle = ToUpload[0];
    VideoPath = ToUpload[1];
    ThumbnailPath = ToUpload[2];
    VideoDesc = ToUpload[3];
    VideoTags = ToUpload[4];
    }
}
```

Serialize (This works, to best of my knowledge, happens every time the program is updated.):

```
public class Serialize{

    public void save (ArrayList<UploadItem> UploadedList)
    {
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("datafile");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(UploadedList);
            oos.close();    
        } 
        catch(Exception e){
           System.out.print(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Deserialize (Not working, happens at startup):

```
public class Deserialize {

    ArrayList<UploadItem> UploadedList;

    public void startup ()
    { 
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("datafile");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            UploadedList.add(ois.readObject());
            ois.close();               
        } 
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.print("Problem in readFile" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException c)
        {
            System.out.println("Class not found");
            c.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Unable" and "not working" are not problem descriptions. Try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are serializing an ArrayList object. when deserializing, you get the same object back (after proper casting).

change the line

```
UploadedList.add(ois.readObject());
```

to

```
UploadedList = (ArrayList<UploadItem>)ois.readObject();
```